# Can I prefer different WiFi networks based on location? MacOS / OSX

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking

So MacOS / OSX has a nice "Network Location feature" that seems to be able to switch between different IP settings, etc, easily. But what I want to achieve is that when I've set "work" location, connect to the work WiFi (e.g. SSID Corpwifi) but if I've set "other" location, even if I'm physically at work, connect to other WiFi (to avoid routing traffic over work WiFi for non work stuff). Problem is, the list of preferred WiFi networks seem to be shared between network locations. Is is something I'm missing in making it possible to prefer different WiFis based on Network location?